# Alter timezone on a user base

Tags: postgresql

I want to change the timezone for the timestamps of a given user.

I don't want to change the timezone of the the entire database.

And I can't set the timezone on a connection/session level; the tool I am using (sqoop does not allow two statements to be given).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a better tool?

More seriously, if the "user" in question is a *database user* not an virtual user at the application level, you can set parameters on the user, e.g.:

```
ALTER USER myuser SET TimeZone = 'UTC';
```

Comment: use a "better tool" is not exactly the answer. There are not may tools around to move data from relational databases into hadoop.

Comment: It might be worth patching sqloop to let you send multiple statements, then. Or even better, let you configure a set of variables to ask it to set. This should get you sorted out for now though.